# asp textbox only accept characters in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, textbox, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a `asp:TextBox` and I need to validate that only accept characters.

Textbox

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txt" onkeypress="return AllowAlphabet(event)" />
```

Javascript

```
function AllowAlphabet(e)
{
  isIE = document.all ? 1 : 0
  keyEntry = !isIE ? e.which : event.keyCode;
  if (((keyEntry >= '65') && (keyEntry <= '90')) || ((keyEntry >= '97') && (keyEntry <= '122')) || (keyEntry == '46') || (keyEntry == '32') || keyEntry == '45')
     return true;
  else
{
    alert('Please Enter Only Character values.');
    return false;
      }
}
```

It works good in `chrome`, `firefox` but doesn't work in `IE8`.

what can I do make to it work?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work for you?

```
function AllowAlphabet(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var keyEntry = e.which || e.keyCode;
    var bIsCharacter =
        (keyEntry >= 65 && keyEntry <= 90) ||
        (keyEntry >= 97 && keyEntry <= 122) ||
        (keyEntry == 46) ||
        (keyEntry == 32) ||
        (keyEntry == 45);
    return bIsCharacter;
}
```

Comment: These solutions I see time and time again are all well and good until you change keyboard layouts and it all goes foobar.